# Retrieve first 5 fields from MongoDb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How to retrieve first 5 fields from `MongoDb` database collection? I even don't know the  length of a database collection. Please tell me the query for retrieving first 5 fields from collection.

This was the question asked me in my MERN stack interview, hope someone will help to find answer for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `.limit(...)` to limit the number of documents returned on a cursor: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/

Comment: In that document itself seeing limit() is applicable only using for  mongo shell method , Actually question is that I need query that is refer to the MongoDB Node.js driver

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/limit

Comment: Yea , Got It . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define an empty query document.
const query = {};
// Sort in descending (-1) order by length.
const sort = { length: -1 };
const limit = 5;
const cursor = collection.find(query).sort(sort).limit(limit);
await cursor.forEach(console.dir);
```